# Buffers with pointers in C

Tags: c, string, copy, buffer

I am confused about a basic C thing here.
I have a buffer of 36 bytes. And I want to write 3 data bytes to that buffer, each of 12 bytes received from diiferent functions.
For simple (may not be efficient) way, what I have done is, I have taken 3 different buffers of 12 bytes each. And using memcpy() I write data into those buffers. And then I use a strcat function to get them into the 35-byte buffer.
Is there any other way of doing it?

```
int main()  
{  
    typedef struct rtc_time_type{  
        int HOUR;  
        int MIN;  
        int SEC;  
    }RTC_TIME_Type;  

    RTC_TIME_Type pCurrentTime;  

    char mainbuff[36], buff1[12], char buff2[12], char buff3[12];  

    memset(mainbuff,0,36);  
    memset(buff1,0,12);  
    memset(buff1,0,12);  
    memset(buff1,0,12);  

    memcpy(buff1, /*int bytes received from some structure*/ pCuurentTime.HOUR);  
    memcpy(buff2, /*int bytes received from some structure*/ pCuurentTime.MIN);  
    memcpy(buff3, /*int bytes received from some structure*/ pCuurentTime.SEC);  

    strcat(mainbuff,buff1);  
    strcat(mainbuff,buff2);  
    strcat(mainbuff,buff3);  

    //send mainbuff on UART  
    UART_Tx_Buff(mainbuff);  

    return 0;  

}
```

Comment: And, in strcat and memcpy, do I need to typecast? Data from the structure is int.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about some code, please make sure it's a minimal, **compilable** testcase.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : yes, Thanks, I forget to flush the mainbuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course there is another way.

The data doesn't seem to be strings, but rather binary data. Then you can't safely use string-related functions like `strcat()`, since they expect strings as inputs (meaning they'll stop if they see a 0-character).

You should be able to just use `memcpy()` directly into the proper places in the destination buffer.

```
char mainbuff[36];  

memcpy(mainbuff + 0 * 12, pCurrentTime.HOUR, 12);
memcpy(mainbuff + 1 * 12, pCurrentTime.MIN,  12);
memcpy(mainbuff + 2 * 12, pCurrentTime.SEC,  12);

//send mainbuff on UART  
UART_Tx_Buff(mainbuff, 36);
```

Note that I added the missing size argument in `memcpy()`, and also gave `UART_Tx_Buff()` a size argument since otherwise it must be operating on strings and thus not appropriate for this.

You don't show the declaration of `pCurrentTime`, so it's hard to know if the syntax is correct. Note that if that variable is a pointer (as the leading `p` suggests), then using the dot operator won't work.

Comment: Okay, if I do memcpy(mainbuff,buff1),it will copy the buff1 into mainbuff. I'll need to increment the pointer in order to write to the mainbuff from 12th byte. How can I do that?

Comment: can I use this:    memcpy(mainbuff,&pCurrentTime,36);